# Issue with dynamic Module Federation in angular when one of the remote application is down

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to implement dynamic module federation where I have a host application and few remote applications.
Let's assume I have hyperlinks **remote1** on my host App and when I click on remote1 link, I will dynamically load remote application App1 at that placeholder.
But, suppose my remote application is down and if I click on hyperlink- remote1, It's throwing console error**strong text**

*Error:Uncaught(in promise):TypeError:Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/remoteentry.js*

This is how I am importing my remote module:

```
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

const routes: Routes = [
    
    {
        path: 'remote1',
        loadChildren: () =>
            loadRemoteModule({
                type: 'module',
                remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
                exposedModule: './Module'
            })
            .then(m => m.RemoteModule)
    },
];
```

Is there a way to handle this error when a remote application is down and when I click on that link I should be able to redirect to another page where I can display a message that remote App is down?

Comment: can anyone help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958591/nx-mfe-angular-module-federation-not-able-to-access-remote-micro-front-end

Answer (score 2):

You can load another module if there is an error during remote module load by using the `catch` block of promise returned by `loadRemoteModule`.

```
loadRemoteModule({
     type: 'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
       exposedModule: './Module'
 })
 .then(m => m.RemoteModule)
 .catch(e => {
    return import('src/app/placeholder/placeholder.module').then(m => m.PlaceHolderModule);
 })
```

And, you can create a `PlaceHolderModule` in shell app - whose default route will load a component with message indicating that `Sorry! Something went wrong.  Click refresh to retry`

Comment: Can we reload the module without refreshing the page for ex. if any of the remote app is down i am showing page not found but after I up that app it should load the app without refreshing the page